# Is"always" a workable term to describe the uptime of a server?

Tags: requirements, uptime, service-level-agreement

since me and my colleagues had a discussion about this, I wanted to ask, if you would use the term "always" to describe the uptime of a server in a requirement.

Example:
The server should be always reachable.

Since, in my opinion, alsways can't be measured, I would rather write the requirement like this:

The uptime of the Server should be >= 99%.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use always, it isn't possible to achieve. Uptime is discussed in terms of nines: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_availability#%22Nines%22

Amazon S3 for example, offers [4 nines of availability](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DataDurability.html) (99.99%).

Look at: https://uptime.is/ to fully understand how much downtime you are allowed for a given sla.